# distance between measures, proof of an inequailty

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\Omega = \prod _{s \in S} \Omega_s$, with $\Omega_s$ finite and all the same, $S$ countable. Let $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ be two probability measures on the product space (not necessarily the product measure). Let $c$ be a coupling between the two measures and let's define,

$$
rift(c) = sup_{s \in S}\{  \, \, \,  c \, \, \{  \omega^1, \omega^2 \in \Omega,\, \, s.t. \, \,  \omega^1_s \neq \omega^2_s\, \} \, \, \}.$$

Then we call distance between the two measures $dist(\mu_1, \mu_2)$ the infimum over all the possible couplings $c$ of the previous quantity. How can I prove that:

If C is a cylinder subset of $\Omega$, specified by $r$ components $\omega_i$, then $\forall \mu_1, \mu_2$ probability measures defined on the product space, $$|\mu_1(C) - \mu_2(C)| \leq r \, dist(\mu_1, \mu_2)$$

Comment: I understood all the words except "coupling".

Comment: A coupling between $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ is a measure $c = \mu_1\, \,  t \, \, \mu_2$ defined on the space of measures of $\Omega \times \Omega$ and which has as marginals $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$.